# How do I implement night mode in Mac (Cocoa) application?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-yosemite, osx-elcapitan

I am new to creating apps on Mac (Cocoa).

Can someone give me pointers on how can I create a night mode feature in a Mac App?

I really appreciate your help in this regards.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by night mode? The dark mode introduced in OS X Yosemite?

Comment: By night mode I mean the way f.lux app (https://justgetflux.com/) works. I want to develop similar functionality in my app.

Comment: Best is, start with the system time, and take this for your calculation for the night time.

Comment: Did my answer fit your needs?

Answer (score 2):

To achieve a night-mode filter, you need to **reduce the exposure to the blue light** (sunlight contains blue light and keep us awake and alert).

The most simple way to remove blue light on your entire app it's use a **Content Filter** on your Views, in my case I use sepia tone.

Select your View and go to the "View Effects inspector"

[image: View Effects inspector]

In Content Filters, click on the "+" icon and add and scroll to "Color Effect" / "Sepia Tone"

[image: Content Filters]

You can adjust the Sepia Tone or pick different color filters to try to achieve a desired effect, but remember the main goal is remove the blue light (Sepia Tone with intensity 1 is enough).

[image: before] [image: after]

If you want to programaticly way to create a filter:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <CoreImage/CIFilter.h>

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CIFilter * sepiaTone = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISepiaTone" keysAndValues:@"inputIntensity", @1.0, nil];
    self.view.contentFilters = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sepiaTone];

}
```

Apple Reference: [Core Image Filters Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CISepiaTone)

Note: Some apps put a red hue layer upon all application Views but you can face some problems with user interactions.